# SQL error when using select into where not exists query

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, where-clause

I'm trying to insert a table into another table,

```
insert into list2([PHONE])
select [column 0] + [column 1] as PHONE
from [list1]
where not exists (select * from list2
where list2.phone = [list1].phone)
```

but I'm getting an error:

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
  Invalid column name 'phone'.`

On `list2`, there are 2 columns, `phone` and `area code`. `phone` has the full phone number and `area code` has the area code.

On `list1`, there are also 2 columns, `column 0` which has the area code and `column 1` which is the first 6 digits of the phone number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the column name case sensitive? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290124%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I assume SQL Server given the format of the error message. If this is wrong, please re-tag with the appropriate database system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allowed to reference column aliases you construct in the `SELECT` list from the `WHERE` clause:

```
insert into list2([PHONE])
select [column 0] + [column 1] as PHONE
from [list1]
where not exists (select * from list2
where list2.phone = [list1].[column 0] + [list1].[column 1])
```

Alternatively, you could place the construction of the `phone` column into a subquery within the `FROM` clause:

```
insert into list2([PHONE])
select PHONE
from (select [column 0] + [column 1] as PHONE from [list1]) l1
where not exists (select * from list2
where list2.phone = l1.phone)
```